# htaccess redirect - remove file extension and change url segment

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

Looking for some .htaccess help here please:-

I'd like to remove the file extension .aspx and then change the first segment from the random number to a single segment "entry".

**Old domain:**

```
http://www.domain.com/*[random-number]*/entry-title.aspx
```

**New domain:**

```
http://www.domain.com/entry/entry-title
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\d+/([^.]+)\.aspx$ /entry/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```